# create intervals with criteria in R

Tags: r, criteria, intervals

This is my head(both)

```
     start        end          omreg
1 2011-01-19    2012-09-21     TRUE
2 2012-01-19          <NA>     FALSE
3 2007-09-01          <NA>     FALSE
4 2011-09-01    2012-01-11     FALSE
5 2008-09-01          <NA>     FALSE
6 2013-09-01    2014-06-12     TRUE
```

As seen, I have a start date and an end date.

The data are for students who started a course on a specific date and end date shows when they were finished with the course.

Each term lasts for 160 days. Which means that one semester lasts for 160 days. 2 semesters of 320 days, etc ...

The interest lies in wether the students passed the course after 160, 320 or 480 days, etc ...

I want to create columns for each semester

Where:
passed = true
failed = false

to pick up students who fared within 160 days i made:

```
    gdk<-(difftime(as.Date(both$end), as.Date(both$start), 

units="days") < 160 & !both$omreg)
```

But then I get trouble picking up students who were ready

between 160 and 320 days.

i.e. <= 320 but  >160 days.

Perhaps easier to say in the interval [160, 320] days ...

This perhaps was a bit messy explained, but I did my best to try to explain my problem.

And what I need help with is how to change the code above to be able to pick out the desired range.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand your problem, however I am not sure if I understood it entirely. You basically do have a problem with values in between 0 and 160, 160 and 320 and so on.

I'd try to subtract the result of the `modulo` operation with 160 from the time difference between `both$end` and `both$start`

So you'll have the next lower number of days and can perform further operations on this value.

So step by step

Assuming your data is

```
start <- (c("2011-01-19","2012-01-19","2007-09-01","2011-09-01","2008-09-01","2013-09-01"))
end <- (c("2012-09-21",NA,NA,"2012-01-11",NA,"2014-06-12"))
omreg <- c("TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE")
both <- data.frame(start,end,omreg)

# calculate the time difference and convert it to an integer
both$x <- as.integer(difftime(as.Date(both$end),as.Date(both$start), units=("days")))

# calculate the modulo
both$y <- both$x%%160

# subtract the module from the time difference so you get a value like 160, 320,..
both$diff <- both$x - both$y

#remove useless columns
both$x <- NULL
both$y <- NULL
```

so your result will look like this

```
       start        end omreg diff
1 2011-01-19 2012-09-21  TRUE  480
2 2012-01-19       <NA> FALSE   NA
3 2007-09-01       <NA> FALSE   NA
4 2011-09-01 2012-01-11 FALSE    0
5 2008-09-01       <NA> FALSE   NA
6 2013-09-01 2014-06-12  TRUE  160
```